# Page performance displaying Excel files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, excel, performance

I have a page that I have added 2 Excel files to be displayed on - the files are located in the site documents folder and do not have much information in them. The performance is very poor though - is this normal or does anyone know what could be causing it? They do eventually display but it slow - as I intend to add more I am concerned I need to take an alternative approach.

Comment: What is the version of your SharePoint? A modern page or a classic page? Whether the site performance works normally except opening the excel file?